# Django template is not rendering vuejs components even if vue js files are injected

Tags: django, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to inject vuejs components inside my django's base template, but unfortunately, the components are not getting rendered. Even though necessary vuejs js files are there.

So, I am injecting the vuejs build's files app.js, manifest.js and vendor.js inside base.html (django template). I created a vuejs component named article-list in ArticleList.vue file.

The problem is inside django's template, I am not being able to access this component. It is rather rendered as html tag inside template. The files are given below:

**base.html**:

```
  <body>
    <header>
    {% include 'backend/nav.html' %}
    </header>

    <div id="app">
    {% block content %}
      {# Use this block for loading CONTENT files from other html files which extend this base.html #}
    {% endblock content %}
    </div>

    <footer>
    {% include 'backend/footer.html' %}
    </footer>

    <script src="{% static 'dist/js/app.js' %}" async></script>
    <script src="{% static 'dist/js/manifest.js' %}" async></script>
    <script src="{% static 'dist/js/vendor.js' %}" async></script>

    {% block js %}
    {# Use this block for loading JS files from other html files which extend this base.html #}
    {% endblock js %}

  </body>
```

**home.html**:

```
{% extends "backend/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Home{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <h3>Vue Js component Below:</h3>
    <article-list>
    </article-list> {# NOT GETTING RENDERED#}
{% endblock content %}
```

**App.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    hello world
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld'
import ArticleList from './components/blog/ArticleList'
export default {
  components: {
    HelloWorld, 
    ArticleList,
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
</style>
```

**ArticleList.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    TEST from vue
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'article-list',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
</style>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add context processors in Django to add and compile VueJS bundle in static directory.
One way of doing this could be using webpack-loader for django and create corresponding bundles through webpack and then passing config to webpack-loader.